# Save filelist array from input-element and access files

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to be able to select multiple files and send them to my backend but can't figure out how.

In app.js I have a usestate that I send as a prop to my file upload-component.

But after selectig the files I get FileList() with correct number of entries but they are all undefined in my file-state.

If I change the onChange function to :

```
(e) => setFiles(e.target.files[0])
```

or any other index I get a correct file. But how do I save the whole file-array directly?

And in the next step when I need to post my files to the backend can I access them by filename or do I need to store them as blobs or byte-arrays to be able to send them in a json-format?

```
import React from "react";

export const FileUpload = ({ files, setFiles }) => {
  return (
    <div className="file-upload">
      <span className="button">
        <i className="material-icons">attachment</i>Choose files
      </span>
      <input
        type="file"
        multiple
        className="multiple-files"
        aria-label="Multiple file upload"
        accept="image/*"
        onChange={(e) => setFiles(e.target.files)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I came up with this solution:

```
  const fileHandler = e => {
      const fileArray = Array.from(e.target.files)
      fileArray.map(f => f["id"] = Math.random() * Math.pow(10,16))
      setFiles(fileArray)
    }
```